# openGL, movable 2D point to 3D point

Tags: qt, opengl, projection, glu

I have a Qt/ openGL application and I display 2D element on screen whose coordinates depend on a 3D object coordinates. It's ok, when I move my 3D world, my 2D element follows well.
Now, I would like to move my 2D element on Y-screen axis in order to change the Y coordinate of my 3D object in openGL. So X and Z of the 3D object don't change, only its altitude Y.

How to do that?

I tried with gluUnproject with the new 2D coordinates but this function returns new (X1,Y1,Z1), you can't tell it "I already know X and Z, give me only Y1 giving those X and Z". And if, I take the returned Y1, and use it with my X and Z, of course, it doesn't work because if I gluProject(X,Y1,Z) it doesn't give me my 2D point.

I also tried that: I have two points (X,Y,Z) of my 3D object, and (X,Y+1,Z). I use gluProject on those 2 points, which gives me (winX,winY,winZ) and (winX1,winY1,winZ1) (of course winX=winX1). I deduce deltaY=abs(winY-winY1) which is the equivalent in pixels of 1 openGL unite on Y axis between my two 3D points. It works well but only if I don't do too big rotation so it's not the good solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like some feedback on this idea: gluUnproject returns a point based on your 2D coordinates AND a third z coordinate specifying the depth of the window coordinate. My suggestion is to use gluUnproject twice, once with 0.0 and once with 1.0 as the Z coordinate, then subtract these two world coordinates to create a vector (starting point being gluUnproject with 0.0), then use this vector to calculate the desired x and z given a y. You can also calculate this vector yourself, which is faster (and a great way to learn this kind of math).

Comment: I don't really understand your idea. In fact, the problem is when you say "then use this vector to calculate the desired x and z given a y". Maybe I wasn't clear in my question but I know my 3D object X and Z coordinates, they are fixed X0, Z0 and don't have to change. I have a starting 3D Y and I gluProject this initial 3D point (X0,Y,Z0) to get a 2D point. Then, I want to move this 2D point, its y 2d coordinate, but only to change the Y 3D point. The problem is that gluunproject gives new (X1,Y1,Z1) and it's wrong to use (X0,Y1,Z0) as new 3D point.

Comment: I made the calculations with your idea but I can't see what the vector got from the substraction represents and how to use it. For example, if my 2D points are (x,y,0) and (x,y,1), I get with gluunproject : (X,Y,Z) for (x,y,0) and (100*X, 100*Y, 10*Z) for (x,y,1). So what do I do with that?